# Bash script - run function passed to script

Tags: bash, shell

I have a script and am passing a command that I want to then run within the script.

Passing the function like:

```
bash ./myscript.sh 'yarn test'
```

I can run the command if I first save it as a variable and then run it like:

```
FUNC=$1

$FUNC
```

But can't seem to figure out how to just run it without first saving it.

EDIT:

I should have been more specific with my example, my code more accurately looks like: (using KamilCuk's reply suggestion)

```
run_command () {
    "$@"
}

run_command
```

Having the value inside of a function in the script won't run the passed command, having it outside as simply `"$@"` will run it.

Is there something different I would need to do to have it run within the function?

Comment: Why don't you write simply `$1` as a command? BTW, you are not passing a function, but the **name** of a function, which is something different. Functions are not first-class objects in bash, and can't be passed around.

Comment: @user1934428 Edited OP to be more clear about what I'm passing. Also have tried simply using `$1` and it doesn't run it.

Comment: [works here](https://replit.com/@kamilcukrowski/ExhaustedTenseGigahertz#main.sh) `I can run the function` it's not a function, it's a command. And you should rather prefer passing `bash ./myscript.sh yarn test` and then do `"$@"` to properly handle corner cases, like spaces  or `*` characters in arguments.

Comment: Start `./myscript.sh yarn test` and run `"$@"`. Otherwise you'll have serious problems when trying to pass arguments with quotes and spaces. Which, now that I read, @KamilCuk already told you. :)

Comment: Apologies, I wasn't accurate with my example in the OP. Have updated the example to show that I'm trying to run the passed command within a function in the script.

Comment: What part of that code doesn't work as-is? `run_command yarn test` runs `yarn test`

Comment: @chivs890 : Using just `$1` **does** work. I just tried it out, by doing `echo '$1' >run1; bash run1 ls`. If you can't get it running, demonstrate exactly how you did it.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe there's something wrong in your script, or yarn can't be found?

Here's an [updated] trivial script and it works ...

```sh
#!/bin/sh

run_command() {
    "$@"
}

run_command $@
```

and when I run it it does run the passed in parameter.

```sh
# /var/tmp/myscript.sh "echo Hi"
Hi
```

You can use the -x option when launching to get a debug trace .. e.g.

```sh
# sh -x /var/tmp/myscript.sh "echo Hi"
L-MacBook:TEST rohan$ sh -x /var/tmp/myscript.sh "echo Hi"
+ run_command echo Hi
+ echo Hi
Hi
```

Comment: Buggy, though. See BashFAQ #50

Comment: Apologies, I wasn't accurate with my example in the OP. Have updated the example to show that I'm trying to run the passed command within a function in the script.

Comment: Yes that updated answer works, thank you. Guessing there is therefore no way to run it within the `run_command` function straight from it being passed in the script? It has to explicitly be passed to that function too?

Comment: @chivs890 - the "$@" - that's all the args passed to run_command ... each function gets it's own set of $1/$2/etc... so no, not unless your pass or save.

Comment: change `run_command $@` to `run_command "$@"`

Comment: @KamilCuk, but that won't work properly if the arguments to the script are quoted: the parameters have to be unquoted _somewhere_ so word splitting can happen. Or use `eval "$*"`

Comment: @glennjackman, the eval approach introduces a bunch of new bugs. I really can't see a circumstance under which it's defensible here.